# Are $U + V$ and $UV$ independent when $U,V$ are independent and standard uniform?

Tags: probability, distributions

This is related a previous question I posted on the product of two independent variables [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560253/pdf-of-the-product-of-two-independent-uniform-random-variables-x-y-sim-u-1-1). As an alternative method, one could note that if $X,Y \sim U(-1,1)$ and $U,V \sim U(-1,1)$ then $Z = XY = 4UV - 2(U+V) + 1 = S - T + 1$. It is easy to show that
$$ f_S(s) = -\frac{1}{4} \ln \frac{s}{4}, \quad f_T(t) = \frac{1}{4} \begin{cases} t & \text{if } 0 < t < 2 \\ 4-t & \text{if } 2 < t < 4 \end{cases}. $$
Then, it remains to consider the difference of these variables and then the shift (+1). At this point, I realize that (while maybe not necessary), it is unclear to me whether $S$ and $T$ are independent. Intuitively, I would think potentially not since $T > 2$ implies that $S > 0$ and so there should be some dependence.

So this question really has two parts: 1) Is there some way to show dependence? 2) Regardless, is there a way to proceed here to arrive at the distribution of $Z$?

Comment: Compute the covariance of $U+V$ and $UV.$  It requires only the most elementary integrals and simple algebra. Once you establish this is nonzero, you are done with the first question. There are many ways to find the distribution of $Z;$ one of the most pleasant is to find that of $\sqrt{XY}$ by integrating out $X$ to obtain a truly simple distribution and then computing its square.  But at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559614 you already claimed you had done an even harder calculation!

Comment: @Gregory Even for uniform variables on [-1,1] (where the covariance is 0) if we just generate random samples for each and make a simple plot of $U+V$ vs $UV$, that alone is enough to convincingly demonstrate the answer must be in the negative (as well as the appearance of the plot suggesting several possible ways to approach a proof).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here's a very simple solution.**  It involves no integration and only the easiest algebra.

Let $X=2U-1$ and $Y=2V-1.$  These are *iid* uniform random variables on $[-1,1]$ and therefore are symmetric about $0:$ that is, $-X$ and $-Y$ have the same distribution, too.  Thus

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Cov}(XY, X+Y) &= \operatorname{Cov}((-X)(-Y),\ (-X)+(-Y)) \\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(XY,\ -(X+Y)) \\
&= -\operatorname{Cov}(XY,\ X+Y).
\end{aligned}$$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are bounded, their covariance exists and is finite.  The only number equal to its own negative is $0:$ that must be the covariance.

Now exploit the basic rules of covariance (bilinearity) to relate this result to what you want:

$$\begin{aligned}
0 &= \operatorname{Cov}(XY,\ X+Y) = \operatorname{Cov}((2U-1)(2V-1),\ (2U-1)+(2V-1)) \\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(4UV-2(U+V),\ 2U+2V)\\
&= 8\operatorname{Cov}(UV,\ U+V) - 4\operatorname{Cov}(U+V,\ U+V)
\end{aligned}$$

Because $U+V$ is not constant, it has positive covariance, whence the left hand side of the last line cannot be zero.  This means $UV$ and $U+V$ have positive covariance and therefore cannot be independent, *QED.*

BTW, if you wish to do the integrals you can compute that the common variance of $U$ and $V$ must be $1/12$ and conclude (from the independence of $(U,V)$) that $$\operatorname{Cov}(UV, U+V)=\frac{4}{8}\operatorname{Cov}(U+V,U+V) = \frac{4}{8}\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{12}\right)=1/12.$$

---

**To find the distribution of $Z=XY,$** observe that it, too, must be symmetric about $0$ and the distribution of its positive part must be that of $UV.$ That distribution function is

$$\Pr(UV \le t) = \iint^{(1,1)}_{uv \le t} \mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v = t(1-\log(t))$$

for $0 \lt t \le 1.$  Consequently

$$\Pr(-t \le Z \le t) = t(1-\log(t)),$$

which is a useful formula for the distribution of $Z.$  In particular, its density at both $\pm t$ must be half the derivative of this expression, giving

$$f_Z(t) = -\frac{1}{2}\log|t|,\ -1 \le t \le 1; t\ne 0.$$

(The density is not defined at $0.$)

The figure is a histogram of a million draws of $XY$, over which is plotted in red a graph of $f_Z.$  They match.

[image: Figure]

Comment: you're in everywhere, do you earn anything here?

Comment: Does the first argument show that XY and X+Y are independent?

Comment: @DaviAmérico no, whuber generously offers his very considerable expertise *gratis*, just like every other contributor of answers. And he moderates as well. We're very fortunate to have his presence. I learn something from whuber several times a week.

Comment: Gregory, my conclusion to the first part of your question is "therefore **cannot** be independent."

Comment: That - at least as far as I follow, says $UV, U+V$ are dependent, but the first part of the proof shows that $XY, X+Y$ have 0 covariance (which I know doesn't necessarily imply independence).

Comment: Also, I believe there is a small typo in the distribution of $Z$ where you have $-t \le t \le 1$ it should be -1, but it won't let me change it.

Comment: Right: but $X$ and $Y$ are not $U$ and $V$!  The point is that $(U,V)$ have *nonzero* covariance.  (Thanks for spotting the typo--I have fixed it.)